# Android Studio Gradle Build fast at first, then slows down considerably

Tags: android, performance, build, android-studio, gradle

I've been having this problem for quite a while. When I first start Android Studio after restarting my computer my application builds quite quickly (most times), but after an arbitrary amount of time, the builds take between 1:30 to 2:30. It's driving me up a wall. When the build time is long, there is also a yellow warning that pops up in the lower left corner of the IDE that says there were warnings in the build. This does NOT pop up when the build time is normal.

Here are the contents of my studio.vmoptions file, if it's relevant.

```
\-Xms128m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Edit: The warnings included are in my opinion nothing critical but here they are.

```
(Not really warnings)
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
warning: string 'pref_header_general' has no default translation.
Warning: can't write resource [.readme] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:.readme])
```

Comment: Does it help to quit and restart Android Studio?

Comment: Not usually. Restarting my computer is not guaranteed to help either.

Comment: So what are the warnings?

Comment: Added to original post.